# Having Trouble calling with making a non-static method

Tags: java

I am currently working on a school project and I am suppose to be able to call for my program to call for a non-static method that would still move my current number forward and backwards. I am at a loss. What exactly should I do? Here is my coding thus far and everything works minus implementing the non-static options.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

    public class PictureViewer {

    final static int MAX_NUMBER = 8;
    final static int MIN_NUMBER = 1;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        showMenu();
    }

    public static void showMenu() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int current_number = MIN_NUMBER;
        boolean Continuation = true;
        while (Continuation) {

            System.out.println("Select One of the Options");
            System.out.println("Option 1: Forward");
            System.out.println("Option 2: Backward");
            System.out.println("Option 3: CreateFileName");
            System.out.println("Option 4: CreateRandomName");
            System.out.println("Option 5: Non-Static Forward");
            int Menu_Option = input.nextInt();
            switch (Menu_Option) {
                case 1:
                    current_number = forward(current_number);
                    System.out.println("The Current Number is: " +    current_number);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    current_number = backward(current_number);
                    System.out.println("The Current Number is: " + current_number);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    String fileName = createFileName(current_number);
                    System.out.println("File Name: " + fileName);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    fileName = createRandomName(current_number);
                    System.out.println("File Name: " + fileName);
                    break;


            }
        }
    }

    public static int forward(int current_number) {

        if (current_number >= MAX_NUMBER) {
            System.out.println(MIN_NUMBER);
            current_number = MIN_NUMBER;

        } else {
            System.out.println(current_number++);
        }
        return current_number;
    }

    public static int backward(int current_number) {

        if (current_number <= MIN_NUMBER) {
            System.out.println(current_number);
            current_number = MIN_NUMBER;
        } else current_number --; {
        }
        return current_number;
    }
    public static String createFileName(int current_number) {

        return "Picture" + current_number + ".gif";
    }

    public static String createRandomName(int current_number) {
        current_number = MIN_NUMBER + (int) (Math.random() * MAX_NUMBER);
        return "Picture" + current_number + ".gif";
    }

    public  void  forward () {
        // overloaded method, use global variable as input and output
    }

    public  void  backward () {
        // overloaded method, use global variable as input and output
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK now is almost everything, please elaborate better your questions like someone willing to learn, not only " is not working", just a free advice ;-)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PictureViewer {

final static int MAX_NUMBER = 8;
final static int MIN_NUMBER = 1;

private int currentNumber;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    showMenu();
}

public static void showMenu() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int current_number = MIN_NUMBER;
    boolean Continuation = true;
    while (Continuation) {

        System.out.println("Select One of the Options");
        System.out.println("Option 1: Forward");
        System.out.println("Option 2: Backward");
        System.out.println("Option 3: CreateFileName");
        System.out.println("Option 4: CreateRandomName");
        System.out.println("Option 5: Non-Static Forward");
        int Menu_Option = input.nextInt();
        switch (Menu_Option) {
        case 1:
            current_number = forward(current_number);
            System.out.println("The Current Number is: " + current_number);
            break;
        case 2:
            current_number = backward(current_number);
            System.out.println("The Current Number is: " + current_number);
            break;
        case 3:
            String fileName = createFileName(current_number);
            System.out.println("File Name: " + fileName);
            break;
        case 4:
            fileName = createRandomName(current_number);
            System.out.println("File Name: " + fileName);
            break;
        case 5: 
            PictureViewer pv = new PictureViewer();
            pv.setCurrentNumber(current_number);
            pv.forward();
            current_number = pv.getCurrentNumber();
            System.out.println("The Current Number is: " + current_number);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static int forward(int current_number) {

    if (current_number >= MAX_NUMBER) {
        System.out.println(MIN_NUMBER);
        current_number = MIN_NUMBER;

    } else {
        System.out.println(current_number++);
    }
    return current_number;
}

public static int backward(int current_number) {

    if (current_number <= MIN_NUMBER) {
        System.out.println(current_number);
        current_number = MIN_NUMBER;
    } else
        current_number--;
    {
    }
    return current_number;
}

public static String createFileName(int current_number) {

    return "Picture" + current_number + ".gif";
}

public static String createRandomName(int current_number) {
    current_number = MIN_NUMBER + (int) (Math.random() * MAX_NUMBER);
    return "Picture" + current_number + ".gif";
}

public void forward() {
    // overloaded method, use global variable as input and output
    this.currentNumber = this.currentNumber +1;
}

public void backward() {
    // overloaded method, use global variable as input and output
}

public int getCurrentNumber() {
    return currentNumber;
}

public void setCurrentNumber(int currentNumber) {
    this.currentNumber = currentNumber;
}
```

}

Comment: I tried this and tried calling for methods such as setCurrentNumber and getCurrentNumber but it wouldn't increment my current number.

Comment: Thank you so much, this just made a whole lot more sense and I was able to figure out so that when calling for he non-static forward and backward it wouldn't go pass the max number of 8 and below the min number of 1. I should've been more thorough when I asked my question. My apologies just I've been stuck on this for over a week and just didn't know what else to do or say. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to have all the methods defined as `static` in order to be called from `main`. You can create an object in `main` and call the same method. This is what I would do:

1. Make all the methods (except `main`) non static (i.e. remove `static` keyword)
2. Change `main` method implementation to create an object of `PictureViewer` class and call `showMenu`, e.g.

   `public static void main(String[] args) {
       new PictureViewer().showMenu();
   }`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I guess I should've mentioned that I have to create an object to call for the method in my non-static class. Here is what this part of the assignment specifies.

Comment: ClassName theobject = new ClassName();   // e.g.   public class ClassName   {  
theobject.method();   // e.g.   call a method that is NON-static using an object
Now we need to create some non-static methods! Overloaded methods are two methods with the SAME name. We can create a method with the same name as long as it has a different number or type of parameters. Add the following OVERLOADED methods to your program:
public  void  forward (  ) {
    // overloaded method
}

public  void  backward (  ) {
    // overloaded method
}

Comment: That's exactly what you will do when you create an object

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make all methods static just keep only Main() static. Using this trick you will be able to access non-static methods easily and also this will save you from Critical Section problem.Follpwing are steps to implement:

1. Remove static keyword from all methods except main().
2.**Replace**

```
showOptions()
```

**With**

```
new PictureViewer().showOptions();
```

Hope this solves your problem :)